# how to retrieve data from php and put on android spinner?

Tags: android

I'm newbie. Now i face this kind of question.

I am using the CustomHttpClient to connect to local server. I was wondering how the a spinner display value from the php and how it would be work? I have no idea on the java code? Can suggest some of the example or site for me ?

Comment: if you are talking about json/xml from webserver then there's a plenty of info on the web like here http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/ from here http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-series-from-sql-php-to-xml-json-to-android-listview/ and i'm sure there's plenty in stackoverflow too. just search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approach I used. Note I've included things such as webpage address(WebPage) here so it's easier for you to see what is going on. I would advice against placing it here because if the host address changes you'll have to go back and change this in your code.

Android side:

```
/**
 * Class for receiving data from server.
 * @author Jonathan B
 *
 */
public class ReceiveData 
{
//FILL IN webPage with link to the All folder on your server.
private String webPage = "http://www.example.com/Receive/";

//File name of the PHP file that is to be used by the method.
private String fileName; 
String delims = " ,\t\n\"\\;{}[]\\()<>&^%$@!+/*~=";

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public ReceiveData()
{

}

/**
 * Pass arguments to PHP file. Then receive data from PHP file.
 * @param file - PHP file in question
 * @param data - Arguments to pass to PHP file.
 * @return output - The data received from server.
 */
private ArrayList<String> receiveData(String file, ArrayList<NameValuePair> data)
{
    InputStream is = null;
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    //Connect and obtain data.
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(webPage+file);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //Parse data into ArrayList and return.
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            //Parse data into tokens and removing unimportant tokens.
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, delims, false);

            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String token = st.nextToken();
                output.add(token);
            }
        }

        is.close();
        //Log output of data in LogCat.
        Log.d("DATA","DATA:"+output);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    return output;
}

/**
 * Gets all  data from GetAllData.php
 * @return output - ArrayList containing  data.
 */
public ArrayList<String> getData(String row)
{
    fileName = "GetData.php";

    //Add arguments to arrayList<NameValuePairs> so we can encode the data and send it on.
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("row", row));

    ArrayList<String> output = this.receiveData(fileName, nameValuePairs);
    return output;
}
```

Now for the php side of things I had a file in the receive foldeer called GetData.php which looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
 * What this file does is it:
 * 1) Creates connection to database.
 * 2) Gets data from database.
 * 3) Encodes data to JSON. So this data can then be used by Android Application.
 * 4) Close database connection.
 */
require_once 'Connection.php';
require_once 'ReceiveAPI.php';

$server = new Connection();
$receive = new ReceiveAPI();

//Retrieve information.
$row = $_POST['row'];

//Connect to database.
$server->connectDB();
$output = $receive->getAllData($row);
print(json_encode($output));

//Disconnect from database.
$server->disconnectDB();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

php service need to return either json/xml data. Assuming json data, this link may help you on [how to do](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b8e470a5be507158).